# Prove that the nonzero solutions to $x^{\prime \prime}+(1+\cos (t \sin (t))) x=0$ are oscillatory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems, sturm-liouville, oscillatory-integral

Prove that the nonzero solutions to $x^{\prime \prime}+(1+\cos (t \sin (t))) x=0$ are oscillatory, that is $x(t)$ has infinitely many zeros.

I think that I have to use Sturm Picone's Comparison theorem but I am clueless about the function I have to compare with. Otherwise, I tried to think in terms of Pruffer angle but didn't get it.

Comment: Try employing comparison tests with theoretical solutions of the equation; Ie. let $v_1(t), v_2(t)$ be primitive solutions to $x'' + f(t)x = 0$. Given $f(t)$ is continuous and $v_1(t)$ has two consecutive solutions $\{t_1, t_2\}$, then $v_2(t)$ has a minimum of $1$ solution(s) over $[t_1, t_2]$. Try generalising this over $t \in \mathbb{R}$